# How to preserve microseconds when converting Decimal timestamps to datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have such values as timestamps from dpkt library (when packets arrive):

```
for ts, buffer in dpkt.pcap.Reader(file):
    #whatever...
```

Reader gives out ts as Decimal, e.g.:

```
print(repr(ts))
Decimal('1536310893.687185000')
```

I'm Trying to convert it to a `datetime`, but I'm getting no microseconds (actually nanoseconds, but for now only microseconds are important)

```
ts_dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts) 
ts_dt
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 7, 9, 1, 33)
```

For some reason, `utcfromtimestamp` does not consider fractional part of Decimal values.

Is it a bug? It worked in Python 2.7

I can  convert `Decimal` to `float`, and it works kinda, but I hate this approach - floats has limited precision. Chances are, at some version it will be broken, by minor changes or I will have imprecise values, that could be a disaster and it would be huge pain to troubleshoot... I prefer to have exact values and accurate calculations whenever possible (especially in such a trivia as converting timestamps)...

So how to preserve microseconds when converting `Decimal` timestamps to `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why this does not work in Python3.6+, but one way to do the conversion without floating point is to use `datetime.replace()` to set the microseconds like:

#### Code:

```
ts_dt = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).replace(microsecond=(ts - int(ts)) * 1000000)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import datetime as dt

ts_dt = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)
print(ts_dt)

ts_dt = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).replace(microsecond=(ts - int(ts)) * 1000000)
print(ts_dt)
```

#### Results:

```
2018-09-07 09:01:33
2018-09-07 09:01:33.687185
```

Comment: OK, it is a temporary solution. It would be great to know why Decimals are converted to integer and fractional part is ignored.

Comment: I am looking at the CPython source.  One possibility is that Decimal was rewritten in C instead of Python for Python 3.  May be an implementation detail there.  Also there has been two different changes in the rounding mode used during the conversion in the last few years.  I will dig a little deeper. If I figure something out I will amend the answer.

Comment: This worked in Python 3.5.1  I would suspect this change: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7667f58151d5efbbae4f0b1d7178f99dad0d74c0.  There is an open issue here: https://bugs.python.org/issue23607

Comment: As an aside there is also a request for nanosecond support: https://bugs.python.org/issue15443

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `Decimal`. It seems, that decimals are converted to int before using in datetime. Convert it explicitly to float:

```
ts_dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(foat(ts))
```

Comment: Floats has limited precision. I don't need floats. there is no floats in time, it is quantized.

Comment: I have Decimals from an output from library dpkt. It worked with decimals in python 2.7, don't know why it doesn't in Python 3.7.

Comment: This is insane btw, why would somebody convert decimals to integer?

Comment: There was a PEP410 proposing decimals as a primary way to go for timestamps. They declined it, because there are too many changes to be done. And what next? they broke Decimals completely? why???

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making it decimal? float datatype works fine.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> ts = 1536310893.687185000
>>> ts_dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)
>>> ts_dt
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 7, 9, 1, 33, 687185)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on kind answers of others, I use this code:

```
def datetime_from_decimal(timestamp):
    if isinstance(timestamp, Decimal):
        whole, fractional = divmod(timestamp, 1)
        mcs = int(fractional * 1000000)
        return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(whole).replace(microsecond = mcs)
    else:
        return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)


datetime_from_decimal(Decimal('1536310895.988003000'))
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 7, 9, 1, 35, 988003)
```